# JQuery AJAX Post Inside Partial View

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

In my C# MVC4 application, I have two main views: "Index" and "Index_Perm."  The logged-in user's role is what determines which of these views is rendered.  "Index" contains a view called "PMain" and Index_Perm" contains a view called "PMain_Lim."  "PMain" and "PMain_Lim" contain another partial view called "Analysis."  Inside of "Analysis", I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SubmitAverage').click(function () {
            var $form = $('#form1');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home/Average",
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    alert("Edit successful");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('failure');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

My issue is that, when "Index" is the main view being accessed this script runs correctly when the Submit button is clicked.  When "Index_Perm" is the main view however, when the button is clicked, the AJAX post fails with the error: `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.` After some investigation in Firebug, I see that it is trying to access:  `mylocalhost/Home/Index_Perm/Home/Average` instead of: `mylocalhost/Home/Average` which is specified as the url to send the POST in my script.
Here is the applicable portion of code which is identical in "PMain" and "PMain_Lim" which contains the button that is tied to the script:

```
    <div id="Analysis" title="Analysis">
        @Html.Action("Analysis", "Home", Model)
    </div>
</section>
<section>
         <h3>
            <button class="btn" id="SubmitAverage" value ="SubmitAverage" name="action:SubmitAverage" type="button">Submit Averages</button>
        </h3>
    </section>
<section>
    <div id="OtherView" title="OtherView" class="OtherChanges">
        @Html.Action("OtherView", "Home", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)
    </div>
</section>
```

Any ideas why its ignoring what I've specified as the URL to use in the JQuery AJAX POST and/or how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the urlhelper in your ajax post

```
url: '@Url.Action("Average","Home")',
```

Comment: I think the definition of that method says it all - *"Generates a fully qualified URL to an action method by using the specified action name and controller name."*

Comment: I understand the definition, I was more interested in why specifying the URL the way I had originally only worked in one scenario.  Thanks all the same for the solution, much appreciated!

Comment: Actually the reason it didn't work the way you intend it is because the url in your ajax post is relative to where it was called. If you did a `url: "/Home/Average"` you will be able to achieve the same thing.